# Return with data does not return any data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`record.data[0]` is an object with data. I'm trying to render this object into HTML, but it does not return any data.

```js
    Object.keys(record.data[0]).map((key) => {
      return <p>{record.data[0][key]}</p>
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your data in `Object.entries` or `Object.values` or `Object.keys()`.

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Example :

**Object.entries()**

```
   const object1 = {
     a: 'somestring',
     b: 42
   };
        
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
       console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
    
    // expected output:
    // "a: somestring"
    // "b: 42"
```

**Object.values()**

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.values(object1));
// expected output: Array ["somestring", 42, false]
```

**Object.keys()**

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```

```js
const data = {
  full_name: 'John Doe',
  date_of_birth: '01-01-1990'
};

const values = Object.entries(data);

console.log(values)

values.map(entry => console.log(entry[0] + " " + entry[1]));
```

Comment: I've done that already, but it does not return in HTML when I do the `return`

Comment: Could you please show all code?